Fredholm-Property of $d/dt - A$
Robin and Salamon studied in this paper $\!$ (preprint) operators of the type
$$
D_A : W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R},H)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R},W) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R},H)$$ defined by $$ \frac{d}{dt}-A
$$
for Hilbert spaces $W,H$ with compact, bounded, and dense inclusion $i:W\rightarrow H$. They showed that if $A:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow C^0(W,H)$ and is self-adjoint, then $D_A$ is Fredholm. My question is: Is there is an simple counterexample if $i$ is not compact? Has anyone some ideas or hints for $W,H$?
